# Two C/C++ libraries calling each others extern functions

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I'm trying to connect two c/c++ projects that depend on each other and this is how I'm doing so far.

**Project A**: I included some header files from project B. The project compiles into libA.so library.

**project B**: I included some headers files from project A and added the libA.so library. So this one can call extern functions from project A. The project compiles into libB.a library.

Then a user program adds libB.a library from project B and starts running the code.

The problem is I need to call some of the project B functions from project A. But project B is compiled after project A so I can't include libB.a. Both projects are large and use different build systems, So I can't compile them together.

Is there any way that I can call functions from project B? Or is there any better way to connect the two projects?

Comment: What is the problem you are running into? What you describe is pretty typical.

Comment: Mutually interdependent libraries, @Jeffrey, are not 'pretty typical'.  Having either A depend on B or B depend on A is quite normal and not in the least problematic.  Having A depend on B _and_ B depend on A is a symptom of bad design and is not normal and is painful to deal with.

Comment: Are the libraries both a mixture of C and C++, or is one a C library and the other a C++ library?

Comment: If they are so dependent on each other, why not make them a single library?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler One of them is a mix of c and c++ and another one is mainly c++

Comment: @Galik They use different build systems. compiling them together would be difficult

Comment: Well it may only be the last step that needs to change. You might still build them separately until it comes to combining the object files into a `.so` file. Maybe you could do that step separately?

Comment: Wait, if one of your libraries is a static library then you should simply need to compile that library first. It shouldn't need to reference the other library's binary at all. And, in fact, the `.so` library would then simply embed the static library within itself obviating the need to distribute both libraries.

Answer (score 1):

When I read and understand your question, it seems that Projects A and B depend on each other, right? This structure is not good.

For overlapping functions, it is recommended to create a new library and refer to it in Projects A and B.

Comment: Yes They depend on each other. You mean creating another library that includes everything from A and B, So A and B don't depend non each other?That would be difficult since they depend on each other too much

Comment: @MRS — Since you seem to be creating Unix-like static archive libraries, not shared libraries, you can simply run something along the lines of: `mkdir C; (cd C; ar x ${LIBA}; ar x ${LIBB}; ar rv ${LIBC} *.o; rm -f *) rm -fr C` or equivalent, assuming shell (environment) variables `${LIBA}`, `${LIBB}` and `${LIBC}` identify absolute pathnames to the various libraries.  Then you can link with `${LIBC}` to get the results (and you don't link with either A or B).  But you've got a mess — you should avoid creating (or inheriting) mutually inter-dependent libraries; it is a complete PITA.